# calculating ranking in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has float score, and I want to rank them from largest to smallest, if the same score, same ranking. I am using MySQL/MySQL Workbench, and any good ideas are appreciated.

Here is a sample input and output,

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 3.50  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.85  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
| 6  | 3.65  |
+----+-------+

+-------+------+
| Score | Rank |
+-------+------+
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 3.85  | 2    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.50  | 4    |
+-------+------+
```

Tried the following query, but not working since it does not handle duplicate,

```
SELECT    id, score,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      TestRank tr, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  score desc;
```

In this above query, user 3 and user 5 have the same score value 4, but ranked differently.

I also tried the following query to just rank score itself, and it returns very weird results,

```
set @curRank := 0;
SELECT    distinct score, @curRank := @curRank+1 as rank
FROM      TestRank tr
ORDER BY  score desc;
```

[image]

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Try searching for dense rank in mysql. It is there in oracle so should have something similar in mysql too

Comment: @Utsav, I think the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql) does not handle duplicate score issue. I tried it is not working for me. I will update post, and good advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to first the do the rank checking before doing the scoring checking first?

Comment: @RyanFung, thanks for the advice, not quite catch you, if you could write your ideas in SQL code, it will be great. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17a49/3

Here's the query that will work for you:

```
SELECT
s.score, scores_and_ranks.rank
FROM
scores s
JOIN
( 
  SELECT
  score_primary.score, COUNT(DISTINCT score_higher.score) + 1 AS rank
  FROM 
    scores score_primary
  LEFT JOIN scores score_higher ON score_higher.score > score_primary.score
  GROUP BY score_primary.score
 ) scores_and_ranks
 ON s.score = scores_and_ranks.score
 ORDER BY rank ASC
```

In the "scores_and_ranks" inner query, we total up the number of distinct scores that are better than the current score.  The top score will have zero, so we add 1 to get the rank value you want.

The reason we have to join to that table (using table "s") is to make sure the duplicate score values (two rows with score=4, for example) are shown in distinct rows.

Comment: smart and smart. Wondering why you are using left join, other than inner join?

Comment: You have to use a left join or the inner query will not return any rows for the score = 4 case.  No rows will be returned because there is no score higher than the highest score.  Kinda confusing but hopefully you get what I'm saying.  :)

Comment: one more question, you are using "LEFT JOIN scores score_higher ON score_higher.score > score_primary.score  GROUP BY score_primary.score", how to know if (1) first execute group by on original table, then left join on group by results, (2) first left join, then group on results of left join. I think you are executing the latter, but want to know why and how.

Comment: BTW, @Mark, met with a new issue after more exercise. Your advice is appreciated, here is the issue => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451858/why-this-left-join-returns-only-one-record

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by "remembering" the previous score:

```
SELECT id, score,
       (@curRank := if(@s = score, @curRank + 1,
                       if(@s := score, 1, 1)
                      )
       ) as rank
FROM TestRank tr CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @curRank := 0, @s := -1) r
ORDER BY score desc;
```

Comment: @Gorden Linoff, dumb question, why using Cross join? :)

Comment: @LinMa . . . As opposed to what?  I *NEVER* use commas in the `FROM` clause, except in MS Access which does not have `CROSS JOIN`.