# why this left join returns only one record?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a sample input, SQL and output, and wondering why only one row is returned? I am using MySQL/MySQL Workbench.

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 3.50  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.85  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
| 6  | 3.65  |
+----+-------+

SELECT
  score_primary.score, COUNT(DISTINCT score_higher.score) + 1 AS rank
  FROM 
    TestRank score_primary
  LEFT JOIN TestRank score_higher ON score_higher.score > score_primary.score
```

Output:

```
+-------+------+
| score | Rank |
+-------+------+
|   3.5 | 4    |
+-------+------+
```

BTW, if I add group by, for this new SQL statement, how do I know if (1) group by is first executed, then left join on group-by results, or (2) left join, then group-by on left join results?

```
SELECT
  score_primary.score, COUNT(DISTINCT score_higher.score) + 1 AS rank
  FROM 
    TestRank score_primary
  LEFT JOIN TestRank score_higher ON score_higher.score > score_primary.score
  GROUP BY score_primary.score
```

Comment: use of aggregate function without group by always returns one and only one row.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, in my case, what do you mean the one row? Thanks. :)

Comment: Invalid SQL statement according to ANSI SQL and most dbms products. To use aggregate functions (e.g. COUNT), either add a GROUP BY clause, or select only aggregate functions (do not mix columns and aggregate functions.)

Comment: @jarlh, thanks for the advice, updated new SQL and appreciate for your inputs. :)

Comment: The left join is performed before the group by. (See Joe Celko's great description at http://joecelkothesqlapprentice.blogspot.se/2006/06/reference-alias-field-name.html)

Comment: @jarlh, thanks for sharing and not 100% agree WHERE is always evaluated after join. I think if we inner join two tables with their own separate where clause, where clause is evaluated first, then inner join? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LinMa I urge you to read the manual (it's surprisingly well written and thorough) before drowning the internet in your unending sea of inane of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using aggregate function (e.g. `COUNT()`) without `GROUP BY` will cause [implicit GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) grouping all rows into a single row.

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

Comment: dumb question, what means group all on rows in my specific case?

Comment: It means that it'll only return single row.

Comment: One row, what is the one row? One row of all original rows in the table?

Comment: It means that the columns using aggregate functions, `COUNT()` in this case, return result of the function. All other columns not specified in `GROUP BY`, i.e. all other columns in this case, are indeterminate. _The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate_. See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) for details.

Comment: thanks for the advice, updated new SQL and appreciate for your inputs. :)